# javascript: throw new error without displaying to user

Tags: javascript

Is there a way that I can use throw new error in javascript and hide the display or change the display of console window?
I am throwing this error just to end the program.

Comment: End the program? This is not C++ ! You can throw an error but change the console window you can't. Console is for users, and you can't hacking them

Comment: If you don't want to display the error then you need to catch it. If you don't want to catch then put your code in an `if..else` block instead

Comment: You cannot remove the error message by default; For the `console`, you can overwrite the `console` API.

Answer (score 0):

Put your program's execution within a try/catch.  Then you can handle the error however you want to.  However, this seems like a pretty hack-ish way to terminate execution.

```
function run_my_program(){
   //Do Everything here
   throw "I want to break the world!";
}
try{
   run_my_program();
}
catch(err) {
    //Do whatever you want with the err
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/s2u67jrg/